# Parsing xml into array using xmllint

Tags: linux, xml, xmllint

I have xml file with multiple `<db>` elements, I need to extract attributes from each node and do some work on them.

IS it possible to load them to array, using ksh and xmllint ?

This is what I have:

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <resources>
        <db>
           <table_name tableid="001" user="mike">customer</table_name>
        </db>
    <db>
           <table_name tableid="002" user="david">orders</table_name>
        </db>
   </resources>
</main>
```

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

tbid="$(echo "cat /main/resources/db/table_name/@tableid" | xmllint --shell data.xml )"
username="$(echo "cat /main/resources/db/table_name/@user" | xmllint --shell data.xml )"

echo $tbid
echo $username
```

Output:

```
/ > ------- tableid="001" ------- tableid="002" / >
/ > ------- user="mike" ------- user="david" / >
```

eventually, I want to get a kind of 2-dim array:

```
arr[0],[0]=001
arr[0],[1]=mike

arr[1],[0]=002
arr[1],[1]=david
```

Notes:
xpath is not supported in xmllint , and can't be installed.
array can be represented in any other way, I just need to be able to extract and do some work.

Comment: Why the attachment to the shell? I could see Python being very effective here...

Comment: this is the requirement for that specific box ( there is  even no java)

Comment: Can you assume that the files will be formatted in approximately the way you presented here (e.g. with the same line breaks), or do you have to work with arbitrary XML?

Comment: Do you have `perl`?, because `XML::Twig` is really good for this sort of job.

Comment: @Sobrique, i will check

Comment: @ Gilles,approximately yes, but what is approximately ?

Comment: Because XML looks like it plain text but isn't. Sometimes you can make a hacky bodge that uses regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer how I'd tackle it, because you don't have any answers yet - I'd use the excellent `XML::Twig` module, and `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'data.xml' );

foreach my $table ( $twig -> get_xpath('//table_name') ) {
   print $table -> att('tableid'), " => ", $table -> att('user'), "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
001 => mike
002 => david
```

Perl has a built in data structure called a hash, that might suit your needs too (depending what you're wanting):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( \*DATA );

my %table_for;
foreach my $table ( $twig -> get_xpath('//table_name') ) {
   my $tableid = $table -> att('tableid');
   my $user = $table -> att('user'); 
   $table_for{$user} = $tableid;
}

print Dumper \%table_for;
```

You can iterate keys in `%table_for` (there's many possibilities, but I'll need an idea of what you want to expand on them)